# Mysql Server 5 vs 6 vs MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Have a simple question here.
I've a database with around 1 billion records, a server with 200GB of ram to handle it.

What do you suggest for best performances? Mysql 5, Mysql 6 or MariaDB?

Comment: MySQL 6 doesn't exist. So that narrows down your options a bit.

Comment: what is this for example? http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/mysql-refman-6.0/index.html

Comment: Really. I fell stupid about the mysql 6 stuff

Comment: The manual you found was for a beta version of MySQL 6 which was cancelled prior to release.

Comment: Thats lots of RAM, `memcached` can actually handle all your data in there :)

Comment: Cadivad, MySQL 6 existed, but it was a development branch and it was cancelled by Oracle. Some of its features are now in MySQL 5.6, and in MariaDB 10.0.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MariaDB 5.3 should give you the best performance:

- It uses the XtraDB (InnoDB improved) storage engine from Percona as
  default.
- The optimizer is greatly improved to handle big data.
- Replication is a magnitude faster in MariaDB if you have lots of
  concurrent updates to InnoDB.

See http://kb.askmonty.org/en/what-is-mariadb-53 for a list of features.